# little vs barely

Tags: word-usage

I want to understand the difference in meaning and the usage between the words "little" and "barely. 
I assume that barely is almost nothing, while little refers to a small amounts but bigger than barely. For example

> Little is known in the literature about something ...
>
> Barely is known in the literature about something ...

I think in the second sentence the meaning is almost nothing while in the first sentence it means few.

Comment: The second sentence is ungrammatical. You can say **hardly anything** to mean almost nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct in your understanding of the difference.

> **Little** is known of...

is more than

> **Barely** anything is known of...

And in another example

> The bikini covered her *(a)* **little**.

is more covered than

> The bikini **barely** covered her.

Answer (score 1):

"Little" can be a noun, an adjective, or an adverb.  "Barely" is only an adverb.  Some examples of the different ways to use "little":

> It was only a *little* dog (adjective)
>
> We see each other very *little*. (adverb)
>
> If you want some ice cream, there's *a little* in the refrigerator. (noun)

While "little" can be used on its own to describe degree of something, "barely" is often paired with other adjectives or prepositions:

> There was *barely any* food left after the family picnic.
>
> Why did you wake me up?  The sun is *barely over* the horizon.

Although like other adverbs it can be paired with verbs:

> The candidate barely won the election in his home state.

So, in your example you would have to say:

> "*Barely anything* is known about ..."

In terms of relative degree, as Peter's answer says, "little" is usually more than "barely".  In order from greater to lesser degree:

> There is *a little* ice cream left
>
> There is *only a little* ice cream left
>
> There is *barely any* ice cream left

In general, "barely" works better if you mean to exaggerate for dramatic effect:

> I'm so tired I can *barely* stand up.